# rails 6.0.0.rc2 - DNS Rebinding & Dynamic hosts - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

If some of you have tried rails 6.0.0.rc2, I am sure you would have come across the dns rebinding protection where we have to whitelist the hostnames. If the app is a multitenant saas app, we will have multiple hosts different according to the customers and it will be dynamic. How to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [test source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/97f1fefcc40f13a74de5925a45e054ba3f98bc86/actionpack/test/dispatch/host_authorization_test.rb#L66), it seems like there is a test for using a Proc or lambda as `hosts` option. Have you tried setting `config.hosts` in your application configuration?

Something like:

```rb
config.hosts = -> (domain) { Client.where(domain: domain).exists? }
```

You can pretty much put any logic in that lambda, and the request will be allowed if it evaluates to `true`.